# Dynamically adding cases to a switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to dynamically add cases to a switch. I want the user to be able to add items and every item needs it's own switch case.

Comment: Unable to visualize the scenario...You code could make it clear....

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use objects with callback functions instead:

```
//You can have initial cases
var callbacks = {
   'something': [() => 42]
};

// and you can create a new entry with this function
function add(_case, fn) {
   callbacks[_case] = callbacks[_case] || [];
   callbacks[_case].push(fn);
}

// this function work like switch(value)
//To make the name shorter you can name it `cond` (like in Scheme)
function pseudoSwitch(value) {
   if (callbacks[value]) {
      callbacks[value].forEach(function(fn) {
          fn();
      });
   }
}
```

and you can add new entries using:

```
add('something', function() {
   // case for something
});
```

**NOTE**:

You can also modify this to work a little bit differently than the original switch because you can have a function that returns a value and use a switch-like expression (like in Scheme where everything is an expression that returns a value):

```
const value = cond(42);
```

Writing this type of pseudoSwitch/cond function is left as an exercise for the reader.

**NOTE 2**:

By default objects in JavaScript use strings as keys and if you need to use something that can't be easily converted to a string, like objects (that will be converted to `[Object object]`) then you can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object that accepts anything as keys. Note that [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) work differently and they are not converted to a string when used as a key in an array.

Answer (score 3):

This was the best/simpler solution for my needs:

```js
const customSwitch = [
    {
        condition: 'case1',
        fn() { /* Do stuff if case1 */ },
    }, {
        condition: 'canBeChangedAnytime',
        fn() { /* Do stuff if case2 */ },
    },
    ...adSomeCasesDynamycallyHere,
]

// edit a condition:
customSwitch[0].condition = 'changed';

// use the switch
for (const { condition, fn } of customSwitch) {
    if (myValue === condition) {
        fn();
        break;
    }
}
```

`customSwitch`, may have the form of an object, which may improve readability. Eg: `customSwitch = { myCond: { condition, fn }}`

You can click the above snippet to see it working ;)

```js
const customSwitch = [    {
    condition: 38,
    fn: val => $("body").append(val === 38 ? 'UP' : 'RIGHT') + ' ',
}, {
    condition: 40,
    fn: val => $("body").append((val === 40 ? 'DOWN' : 'LEFT')+ ' ') ,
}]

$('#option1').click(function () {
    customSwitch[0].condition = 38
    customSwitch[1].condition = 40
});

$('#option2').click(function () {
    customSwitch[0].condition = 39
    customSwitch[1].condition = 37
});


$(window).keydown(function (e) {
    for (const { condition, fn } of customSwitch) {
        if (e.keyCode === condition) {
            fn(e.keyCode);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.btn {
cursor:pointer;
padding:5px;
border-radius:5px;
background-color:#3C0;
margin-top:5px;
width:150px;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Press the four arrow keys:<br>
-if you click <b>option1</b> the switch will recognize UP and DOWN<br>
-if you click <b>option2</b> the switch will recognize LEFT and RIGHT<br>

<div id='option1' class='btn'>OPTION 1</div>
<div id='option2' class='btn'>OPTION 2</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: That would require knowing the number of elements the array would have, which if you're trying to build dynamically you most likely wouldn't know.

Comment: You can have for example a big array with empty elements, like this it will not be undefined but still be configurable...Like placeholders the user can dynamically use (that's what I do usually)

Comment: If your going this route, it may be simpler to have 2 arrays (and no switch case). One for ```case``` strings and another for ```case``` functions. Then you can find the ```indexOf()``` the string and call the function from the function array at that index.

Comment: Or even better, an object! That is what I do often : `{ caseA() { ...doStuff();}, caseB() {...doElse...}}`. But sometimes you just need a switch

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) for switch cases. One of the advantages of using `Object` instead of `Array` for the case is that it drastically reduces errors caused by wrong indexes in `Array`. Using `Object` for cases, you can also extract your case values into another script. This helps for [Single Responsibility Principle](https://www.toptal.com/software/single-responsibility-principle) by concerning you only implementing business logic inside switch cases instead of worrying about maintaining the right case values.

```js
const OP = {
    ADD: 'ADD',
    MULTIPLY: 'MULTIPLY',
};
const choice = 'ADD';
switch (choice) {
    case OP.ADD:
        console.log('You chose add');
        break;
    case OP.MULTIPLY:
        console.log('You chose multiply');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('Operation is not defined');
}
```