# Want to add new cases dynamically in switch statement using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var value = 1;
switch(value) {
case 1:
    // do somthing
    break;
case 2:
    // do somthing
    break;
default:
   // do somthing
    break;
}
```

Now, I want to add some more case like "case 3", "case 4", etc. **run time**. On click event of button. How can i do this using jQuery.

Comment: you want to alter the code when press button?

Comment: Yes, want to add on button click.

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769144/dynamically-adding-cases-to-a-switch

Comment: In this they have used object not switch statement.