# Javascript using a switch statement with `case x` for a wide range of numerical values x

Tags: javascript

I wish to use `case` within a switch switch statement like so:

```
case 'transfer' + amount:
        sql.get(`SELECT * FROM scores WHERE userId ="${userID}"`).then(row => {
            sql.run(`UPDATE scores SET points = ${row.points - amount} WHERE userId = ${userID}`);
            bot.sendMessage({
                to:channelID,
                message: `You have transferred ` + amount + ` points. You currently have ${row.points} points.`
            })
break;
```

If it sees `transfer10` I want the code to take that value 10 to be `amount` however I have no idea how to do that. 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can create switch statement with dynamic-generated `case` statements. I also do not see any real advantage of doing this, plus the logic behind this it would be hard to understand from anyone else who will be reading the code.

What about using the `switch` statement do determine the *art of action* and accessing the _amount_in the `case` statements ?

```
var amount, action;
// some code
...
amount = 2;
// some code
...
action = 'transfer' // or delete, update ...
// some code
...
switch(action) {
  case 'transfer':
    // do some SQL and access the amount
    ...
    break;
  case 'delete':
    // do some SQL and access the amount
    break;
  default:
    // some default action
}
```

If you really need something like a dynamically-created switch-statement look at the first answer [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769144/dynamically-adding-cases-to-a-switch).

Comment: Hmm that could work. Only things is that it would be best if amount ranged from at least 1 to 50 and this might make things a tad... lengthy.