# How to add dynamic switch case in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here i am having an array . Eg:

```
let places = ["tamilnadu","andhra","maharashtra","kerala"]

switch (value) {
  case "tamilnadu":
    break;
  case "andhra":

    break;
  case "maharashtra":

    break;
  case "kerala":

    break;
  default:

}
```

is there any way i can loop the array and populate the values in cases in switch. Any idea

Comment: Assuming you could generate dynamic `case` calls depending on the values inside the array, what code would go inside those `case` calls? Do you want to generate dynamic statements as well?

Comment: No, what's the purpose of your idea?

Comment: Depends on what you're doing inside each case block. Is the operation consistent for all values or they have separate functionalities?

Answer (score 0):

Switches are just if/else statements:
So you could use a for loop and check if they match:

```
let places = ["tamilnadu","andhra","maharashtra","kerala"]
for (const place of places) {
    if(place === value) {
        // Do what you need to do 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use object with callback functions as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35769291/9053019)

Comment: Please add the reference if you are taking the code from another answer.