# Dynamically add cases to a switch using a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that will be populated with an unknown number of elements.

```
myArray = ["a", "b", "c",...]
```

I want to create a switch statement so that it contains all the cases contained in `myArray`.

The outcome I would like is something like:

```
switch (true) {
    case myVariable === 'a':
    // DO something
    break
    case myVariable === 'b':
    // DO something
    break
    ... KEEP REPETING FOR EACH ELEMENT IN myArray
}
```

Clearly, I cannot hardcode all the cases because I do not know how many there are and how they are called.

My idea was to create a loop inside the switch as follow:

```
switch (true) {
    myArray.map(myElement => {
    case myVariable === myElement:
    // DO something
    break
    })
}
```

I do not think this is possible because switch expects a `case` not a `.map`

I check this answer [Dynamically adding cases to a switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769144/dynamically-adding-cases-to-a-switch) but it does not address the loop part

Comment: Maybe you do to not need switch at all? Why not just use map?

Comment: Is it a "use switch or die" situation? I would like to think this is when a `for` loop would suffice.

Comment: What is the action for each case ? If variable is "a", what action do you want to perform, if variable is "b" what action you want to have in case. How are actions defined ?

Comment: You could do it with `eval()`. However I would not recommend to use that since it has downsides because of security and performance. As others mentioned a simple loop would do the trick too.

Comment: We need to know how the functions (and their respective arguments, if any) are associated with the elements of myArray. For example, do you start with three parallel arrays (cases, functions, arguments)? Or does my array contain objects that hold all three pieces of information for a given case? Or are the functions actually "parameterless" methods whose names exactly match the case strings?...

Comment: Please look at my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

What you're probably looking for is just to iterate on every element in the array, check the condition, and act accordingly.

```
myArray.map(myElement => {
    if (condition)
    {
        //Do something
    }
})
```

That's the best way I can think of.